# What is wrong with the rection

Tags: organic-chemistry

I had a reaction in which I have to find the product .

I figured out something .

[image]

But my sir told me that this is a wrong product . I could understand why , as the reagent used act as decarboxylation .

Comment: There's no stabilized anion. Decarboxylation seems unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decarboxylation proceeds through free radical mechanism...and we see scope for rearrangement of radical...to obtain more substituted product(thermodynamic product....as we are supplying heat)and hence we can obtain the product 
2-Methylbutan-2-ene...Hopefully thats your product

Comment: Do you have a reference that the reaction proceeds through free radical mechanism?

Comment: I don't see why this reaction *would* proceed through a free radical mechanism. The reaction could just decarboxylate and pick up a proton on the far left carbon through resonance.

Comment: sir,im still a student, and have learnt that thermal decarboxylation proceeds through a radical mech....in case you think otherwise...please do enlighten me too..regards@SendersReagent

Comment: moreover...whatever charged intermediate it forms...it can rearrange to give a thermodynamic product